# Should I contain time as a random variable in repeated measurement?

Tags: mixed-model, multiple-regression, linear-model

I have a dataset which contains happiness scores of several subjects, measured three times within a day (in morning, afternoon and evening) and repeated across several days. But during how many days happiness was measured varies between subjects, and there are different missing time points for these subjects.

The first thing I want to do is to model happiness score against the task variables. So my model is like:

`Happiness ~ task-related varibale + (1|subject)`

Then I want to know how the time (morning/afternoon/evening, specified as 1,2,3 which is a continual variable) and it's interaction with  task-related variables influence the happiness score, considering the days as different samples. So I used a linear mixed model like this:

`Happiness ~ time*task-related varibles + (1|subject) + (1|day)`

My question is that I am not sure whether the two models are right.Should I model day and time as random effects in model 1 if I only care about the effect of task variables? If so, should it be nested or crossed?

For the model 2, if I care about the time and the time is a fixed variable, should I still model it in the random effect?

Sorry about asking maybe a simple question, I am new to linear mixed model. I have thought about it but still not sure about it. So thanks for any opinion!

Comment: Have you checked whether the patterns you observe per individual are repeatable between days ?

Comment: You don't necessarily need to model day effect at all. And as time (morning, afternoon, and evening) is in your model of interest as a categorical predictor, you can't put it in as a random effect grouping variable too (categorical predictor uses the same variance as random effect grouping variable). However, as CaroZ says, it's possible that days are not interchangeable in terms of your effects. So it might be safer to model it in. Your second model seems reasonable to me.

Answer (score 3):

When thinking of time I think of fixed effects and serial correlation first as detailed [here](https://fharrell.com/post/re).  A semivariogram is a must-do graphical diagnostic to understand correlation patterns.  Correlation matrices also help.

You seem to be modeling the happiness score as if it's continuous with no floor or ceiling effects.  If that's not the case consider ordinal longitudinal models, e.g., [this](https://hbiostat.org/rmsc/markov).

Depending on correlation patterns you find with diagnostic plots, it may be OK to model serial correlation using one flexible pattern, whether it's a short-term or long-term correlation issue.  It may be possible to dispense with all random effects.